# Next.JS 13 and Iron-Session

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am currently having an issue switching from Next.JS /pages to /app directory when using Iron Session. Currently writing an API Route that is supposed to be a get request that takes an access token and saves it to a user's local storage. This worked easily in Next 12, but with Next 13 the following code produces a "POST http://localhost:3000/api/exchange-public-token 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

```
import { withIronSessionApiRoute } from 'iron-session/next';
import { plaidClient,sessionOptions } from '@/lib/plaid';
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';


export async function GET(){
  withIronSessionApiRoute(
    async function handler(req:NextApiRequest, res:NextApiResponse) {
      const exchangeResponse = await plaidClient.itemPublicTokenExchange({
        public_token: req.body.public_token,
      });
      console.log(exchangeResponse)
      req.session.access_token = exchangeResponse.data.access_token;
      await req.session.save();
      res.send({ ok: true });
    },
  sessionOptions
  )
}
```

Iron Session doesn't seem to have made any updates for Next 13, so I'm wondering if there is a workaround for saving to a user's local storage. P.S.--I don't *need* to use Iron Session, so if there is a better tool, I'm open to trying that instead. Thanks!

I tried to change the function names, reading the Next /app directory docs, as well as Iron Session.

Comment: Checkout this thread: 
https://github.com/vvo/iron-session/issues/560

Comment: According to your error massage, you need to name your function POST and not GET!